# WIFI (driver) not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, modprobe

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. The Wifi Adapter, which works on Windows through automatic driver installation, is not working on it. Through help with a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384405/errors-in-installing-the-wifi-driver) I installed the updated driver but the WIFI panel is still absent in the title bar after the reboot. Running `sudo modprobe rtl8188gu` results in `modprobe: FATAL: module rtl8188gu not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic`.

[This](https://github.com/McMCCRU/rtl8188gu) is the driver repo. As mentioned in the repo wiki to run `eject /dev/cdrom0` results in `eject: /dev/cdrom0: not found mountpoint or device with the given name`. The command doesn't work with `./dev/cdrom0` or just `cdrom`.

I have little knowledge of Linux and CLI. Your help is highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0bda:b711 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188GU 802.11n WLAN Adapter (After Modeswitch)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

```
$ sudo modprobe 8188gu
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8188gu': Exec format error
```

**Edit 2:**

```
hammad@hammad-linux:~$ (dmesg; modinfo 8188gu) | nc termbin.com 9999
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
nc: getaddrinfo for host "termbin.com" port 9999: Temporary failure in name resolution
hammad@hammad-linux:~$ sudo (dmesg; modinfo 8188gu) | nc termbin.com 9999
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `dmesg'
hammad@hammad-linux:~$ (sudo dmesg; modinfo 8188gu) | nc termbin.com 9999
nc: getaddrinfo for host "termbin.com" port 9999: Temporary failure in name resolution
[sudo] password for hammad: 
hammad@hammad-linux:~$ (sudo dmesg; modinfo 8188gu) | nc termbin.com 9999
nc: getaddrinfo for host "termbin.com" port 9999: Temporary failure in name resolution
hammad@hammad-linux:~$ modinfo
modinfo: ERROR: missing module or filename.
hammad@hammad-linux:~$ modinfo 8188gu
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188gu.ko
version:        v5.2.20.2_28373.20180619
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     0134ED43BF3F55F2E3E0DD4
alias:          usb:v0BDAp2005d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDApB711d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           8188gu
vermagic:       5.11.0-44-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
param...(shortened for body characters limit here)
hammad@hammad-linux:~$  nc termbin.com 9999
nc: getaddrinfo for host "termbin.com" port 9999: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Also, the driver it builds is 8188gu and not rtl8188gu. Does this work? `sudo modprobe 8188gu`

Comment: @chili555 I have added the outputs of both commands to the question.

Comment: Edit to include URL from terminal for `(dmesg; modinfo 8188gu) | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have included the output for the command.

Comment: "Exec format error" sometimes happens when you want to use a module compiled for a different kernel version. It could be because you forgot to reboot in between 2 alterations (you are still on the old kernel and the module is expecting the new kernel). Please reboot and then do: `cd rtl8188gu && make clean && make && sudo make install` Now does `sudo modprobe 8188gu` succeed?

Comment: @chili555 I read the commands on askubuntu and have tried it, it results in the same error. What does it mean to " reboot in between 2 alterations"?

Comment: It means, for instance, that Update Manager installs a newer kernel version and, before the reboot, you build the driver. After rebooting into the newer kernel, the driver built for the *older* kernel won't work.

Comment: Have you fully updated the system? `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade` followed by reboot?

Comment: From the answer to the original question, between `make install` and `reboot` there was the command to `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware`. Could it have caused it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134296/discussion-between-chili555-and-hammad-ahmed).