# RTL8188GU wireless USB adapter doesn't work with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2d95:600a vivo V2152
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b711 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188GU 802.11n WLAN Adapter (After Modeswitch)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 30fa:0300  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's your hardware setup?

Comment: I have tried all the things which i found from the internet

Comment: @frippe please check my hardware config in below image https://ibb.co/5Ys2hLJ

Comment: It is not a related hardware config. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. Please post it as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @Pilot6 this command does not return anything

Comment: Are you using a USB wireless adapter or is it built-in?

Comment: Currently i am using `USB tethering`. otherwise i have USB wireless adapter

Comment: @Pilot6 please check below image, i have used `lspci -knn` and it returns https://prnt.sc/SUbPXPkLcNnD

Comment: Please post terminal output as text and post it to your question using the [edit] link. Please don't post screenshots of a terminal.

Comment: If your question is about a USB wireless adapter, then post output of `lsusb` command. AS TEXT PLEASE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138188/discussion-between-krupal-vaghasiya-and-pilot6).

Comment: You need to search for drivers for RTL8188GU or wait till someone suggests where to get them.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for suggesting `RTL8188GU` i have installed and reboot the system and my wifi is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errors in installing the WIFI driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384405/errors-in-installing-the-wifi-driver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My WIFI issue is resolved. I have installed `RTL8188GU` driver and reboot the system.

Please follow the below steps:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/McMCCRU/rtl8188gu.git
cd rtl8188gu
make
sudo make install
cd .. 
rm -rf rtl8188gu
sudo reboot
```

After rebooting the system Wi-Fi should work.

Comment: This is great that you found the solution! But if there is a dkms install way, it is better to use that method because installing with `make` will break after a kernel upgrade. The `dkms` in the first line suggest that the author has a dkms method too.

Comment: @Pilot6 so i have to install `dkms`?

Comment: You already installed `dkms`, but the installation procedure didn't use it.

Comment: I looked into that git readme and it doesn't have `dkms.conf`. So you'll need to re-install the driver starting with `cd rtl8188gu` after each kernel upgrade, unless you create a dkms. And you don't need `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware`.

Comment: Okay, so did you know how to use it. because i don't want to face any problem when kernel is upgrade

Comment: Yes, I know. But it requires some work. You can search how to create a dkms package and try it yourself. If you have problems, you can ask a question.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have found `sudo apt-get update -y` and `sudo apt-get install -y dkms` commands. this should works?

Comment: You already installed dkms. I am afraid you don't have enough knowledge to create a dkms package. It is not about running some commands you find in the net. You need to understand first what dkms is, then write your own `dkms.conf` file. Then install the driver using that file. If it is too complex for you, leave it as is for now. But when Wi-Fi stops working, install the driver again. You won't need an internet connection for that if you keep the source.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running

> *"sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms"*

but it is showing me error as:

Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It seems you may have added a comment in the answer section though. If you need to update your question with more info, feel free to edit the question at any time.